# Getting customizer class error in case using BarChart: BarRenderer cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport, jfreereport

I am trying to use the customizer class *BarRenderer* from *jFree* charts to customize a bar chart, I have added the jar to the classpath and added the class to the customizer class section of the Bar Chart properties as *org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer* and I keep getting the error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not create chart customizer instance.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer
```

Is there something I am missing or forgot to do here, any help to get this running would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A customizer and a renderer are two different animals: the renderer is responsible for painting a part of the chart while the customizer lets you customize it.

What you need to do is create a class that extends `JRChartCustomizer` and in the customize method set the `BarRenderer`:

```
public class MyCustomizer extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
        if (chart.getPlot() instanceof CategoryPlot) {
            CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setRenderer(new BarRenderer());
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your design you need to set the customizer to `MyCustomizer` and make sure that your class is in the classpath